# How to call functions with variable parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to type text into the textbox and when I click the button have it alert me the text. I can't seem to get the variable to work in the function. I'm not sure if "var i = document.getElementById('apple').value;" is correct.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function(event){

alert(i);});

<form>
Enter:<br>
<input type="text" name="inputbox" id="apple">
<input type="button" name="alert" value="alert">
</form>

<script>
var i = document.getElementById('apple').value;

document.querySelector("input[type=button]")
     .addEventListener("click",function(event){

alert(i);});
</script>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/QyKvme

I also tried:

```
var i = form.inputbox.value;
```

but that didn't work either

Comment: You have to put the line that gets the value ***inside*** the event handler for click. Right now it only gets the value on pageload, not everytime you click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("input[type=button]")
.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  var i = document.getElementById('apple').value;
  alert(i);
});
```

You need to query for the value *at the time of click*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are storing the element's value in a variable when the DOM loads. Therefore when the `click` event is fired, the `value` property is an empty string (or whatever the value was when the DOM loaded).

Retrieve the value when the `click` event is fired instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpKRQ)

```
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var value = document.getElementById('apple').value
  alert(value);
});
```